# Could i merge this two select query in one?

Tags: php, mysql, select, merge

My aim is to show/display in the right part questions of the survey (from a table of my database)   and  in the left part  answers from customers (from another table in my database) in the right part.    So my question  is : How to merge this two select query ?   I did some research but with php it's kind of tricky to understand and I'm still new on php too.
Any help or advices are welcome .

Best Regards A.V.

```
<?php
    include("bdconnect_Foredeck.php");
    $link=mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);

    if(isset($_POST["bouton55"])){
        $link = mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);  

        $id = $_REQUEST["Zoubi"];
        $ClientRef =$_REQUEST["KGB"];

        $rechercheq = "SELECT Qref,Ref,Question FROM questionnaire WHERE Qref ='$id' ";
        $recherche= "SELECT choix,commentaire FROM reponse WHERE RefQ ='$id' and ref_Client ='$ClientRef'";

        mysqli_query($link,$recherche);
        mysqli_query($link,$rechercheq);

        $result1=mysqli_query($link,$rechercheq); 
        $result= mysqli_query($link,$recherche);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result,$result1)){
            $Ref =$row["Ref"];
            $Question       =$row["Question"];
            $Choix =$row["choix"];
            $Commentara =$row["commentaire"];

            echo" <tr bgcolor=\"white\">
            <td>  $id  </td>
            <td> $Ref </td>
            <td>$Question </td>
            <td>$Choix       </td>
            <td>$Commentara         </td>
            </tr>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are executing each query _twice_, only storing the results the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a JOIN

```
    SELECT a.Qref, a.Ref,a.Question , b.choix, b.commentaire
    FROM questionnaire as a 
    LEFT JOIN reponse as b ON  a.RefQ = b.RefQ
    WHERE a.Qref ='$id' 
    AND b.ref_Client ='$ClientRef'
```

if you have duplicated rows  .. then you can use  distinct

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.Qref, a.Ref,a.Question , b.choix, b.commentaire
    FROM questionnaire as a 
    LEFT JOIN reponse as b ON  a.RefQ = b.RefQ
    WHERE a.Qref ='$id' 
    AND b.ref_Client ='$ClientRef'
```

otherwise  you logic don't permit a single query

Comment: At line 3 of your comment are you sure i have to put a " ; ? or maybe it's after '$ClientRef' at line 5 ? @scaisEdge

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Foredeck\foredeck_searchclient.php on line 65 :  `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result,$result1)){`

Comment: there was a typo  .. answer  updated ..let me know .. and change inner join with left join if the  condition don't match

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.RefQ = b.RefQ
    WHERE a.Qref ='mc2' 
    AND b.ref_Client ='mk1'' at line 3  i did a test with values "mk1'' and ''mc2'' and it's not working .

Comment: The only problem that i have now is that i have some duplicate display . Could you add me or skype then i could sell you my a sql file of my database and see what is going on ?

Comment: Ok still the same problem so what i m gonna do is : add a column for question in customer table then i will use a single select to output all values line by line but thx for your help your answer is good . It's kind of tricky to do a Select with two auto increment row in both tables.